# status bar not showing in vs 2008 tools

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I am learning VB.Net from an already running project. when i am analyzing there is windows.forms.statusBar type control, BUt nothing listed in our tool box .Experts , can you help me about this control. Is that created without using the toolbox ? Created by  using handwritten code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create the status bar using the StatusStrip tool in the toolbox. I hope this helps.

Comment: I found the answer too. StatusBar is the control used in vb6 and its replaced by StatusStrip in VS 2005 Onwords. So the current project development started from vb6 the upgraded to vb.net. For more info [http://vbcity.com/forums/t/157033.aspx]